# Facebook app to edit posts

Tags: api, facebook

Is it possible to make a Facebook app which edits user's post on his wall automatically (edits EVERY POST that user makes, app has user's permission and everything)
I don't think that's possible, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the Graph API docs, I actually think it could work.

1. Get the extended permission called
   "offline_access".  See
   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions
2. Periodically pull from
   https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed
   to see if the user has posted new
   posts.
3. If so, for each new post that has appeared:
4. Pull and store the text of the post.
5. Manipulate the text as desired.
6. Delete the original post using
   "DELETE".  See
   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#deleting
7. Publish your modified version of the
   post using "POST".  See
   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing

Comment: I see, but that wasn't really what I was expecting. Thanks!

Comment: One more question, is it possible to make a fb app to run automatically? With 10min intervals etc.

Comment: Since your app is just code running on your server, you can program it to do stuff whenever you want.  As long as you have the `offline_access` permission, you are not restricted to acting whenever you get a callback from facebook.  Instead, e.g., you can write code that includes a timer that every 10 min calls any other part of your code.  E.g. in Python use a `ttimer` with a callback.  Or in PHP, use an infinite loop with a `sleep` command in it.  (Just make sure you separate that infinite loop from the program that facebook calls or you will never return the data a user requests. :P )

Comment: @EvolvedAI, do you think the method you describe in the answer could be used to [edit all past posts a user has made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555091/does-the-facebook-api-allow-for-automated-changes-to-old-post-visibility), or are there likely to be bugs?

Answer (score 1):

@Jon: You cannot delete a post that your application has not published.
See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it's not possible for security reasons.  Even though you probably have the best of intentions, there are lots of people who unfortunately don't.  The few ruin it for all.

Comment: It must be the same [for changing older posts as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555091/does-the-facebook-api-allow-for-automated-changes-to-old-post-visibility), correct?