# Does the Facebook API allow for automated changes to old post visibility?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps

In other words, is there an API that would allow a Facebook user to change their posts (through a 3rd party app), which are older than a specified date, from being visible to the list "Friends" to another one such as "Only Me" or "Close Friends"?

People are increasingly adding their professional and acquaintance contacts as Facebook friends.

It makes sense to limit the visibility of your posts — to cater to different audiences.

Going forward, that's easy as [Facebook provides ample controls](https://www.facebook.com/help/233739099984085):

[image: Post audience]

However, the issue is that unless you had set it up like that from the start, **[there's no existing function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27092/preventing-new-friends-from-seeing-old-facebook-posts/27263) to *automatically* change the visibility of all of your old wall posts** and photos to "Only Me", "Close Friends", and so on.

This poses a problem, because **[manually](https://www.facebook.com/help/233739099984085) going through posts one-by-one** as far back as [December 2004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Wall) **is not viable**:

[image: Facebook post visibility change]

When introducing Timeline, Facebook did provide a [function to change all posts from "Public" to "Friends"](https://www.facebook.com/help/236898969688346/):

[image: Change past post visibility]

But it is not yet possible to **change the audience of posts older than a certain date** to "Only Me", "Close Friends", "Friends; Except: Acquaintances", etc.

However, it's clear that the underlying functionality to do that is there somewhere.

Are any functions available in the Facebook APIs for potentially building an application for that? If so, which?

Comment: Are you using the JavaScript SDK, or the C# SDK, or neither? (I find it highly unlikely that you're using both.)

Comment: @michaelb958, the question can be relevant for either — the tags are not there to mislead anyone

Comment: @michaelb958, no worries, crafting an answer?

Comment: Maybe. This isn't my best area, and I'll need to investigate first.

Comment: There is __no__ functionality to edit user posts via API at all – not for content, not for privacy settings.

Comment: The original answer is still mostly correct - some edits are possible but typically apps can only edit posts they created, so the use-case outlined here is still not possible

Answer (score 7):

There is **no** functionality to edit user posts via API at all – not for content, not for privacy settings.

> Typically apps can only edit posts they created. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555091/does-the-facebook-api-allow-for-automated-changes-to-old-post-visibility#comment56032581_16555091)

Comment: So anyone knows another way to batch edit old posts (selenium browser, autohotkey...)? Is it possible with Facebook Python SDK?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the only option is to use an unofficial Facebook API. I'm looking at the [Facebot](https://github.com/davidyen1124/Facebot) module to achieve this, will report back on if it works.

Comment: Yeah I would like to know too!

Comment: I ended up building something that was kind of intense and requires you to manually grab some tokens, copy the updated DOM to a clipboard and then save it and run a Node script. I can open source it if you guys are interested

Comment: Can you please open source this ? Thank you.